# How can i center one bootstrap column/form in the exact center of my screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, center, col

I've tried for hours but cannot find a solution, my problem:

Im trying to create a page login page where the login form is horizontal and vertical centered in the page. I'm working with syncfusion blazor and created the container full screen:

HTML:

```
<div class="control-section" style="min-height: 100vh !important; background-color: red !important;">
    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
   margin: 0 !important;
   padding: 0 !important;
}

.container {
 max-width: 100% !important;
 width: 100% !important;
 height: 100% !important;
 padding-right: 0px !important;
 padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.pb-3 {
  padding-bottom: 0rem !important;
}
```

This works and the container is set to full width and height without any scrollbars.

However I'm trying to create one column in this page which is vertical and horizontal centered in center of page.

Note: I want to keep the background of container red because I want to display an full screen image there once column/login form is finished. Therefore im unable to use rows I think?

What I've tried so far:

```
<div class="control-section" style="min-height: 100vh !important; background-color: red !important;">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 offset-5" style="background-color: blue !important;">Test</div>
</div>
```

This created a column with width of 2 and offset of 5 so its centered horizontal, however I'm unable to center or vertical.. Can anyone help me out with this?

**UPDATE** after answer

I used the centerArea code of answer and put the form inside my row:

.HTML:

```
<div class="control-section centerArea">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2" style="background-color: blue !important;">
        <section>
            <form id="account" method="post">
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 150px !important;">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox d-inline-block">
                        <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                            <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-inline-block">
                        <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Password?</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>
                        <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Password?</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a id="resend-confirmation" asp-page="./ResendEmailConfirmation">Resend email confirmation</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

.CSS:

```
<style>
body, html {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.pb-3 {
    padding-bottom: 0rem !important;
}

.centerArea {
    min-height: 100vh !important;
    background-color: red !important;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.form-group {
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    max-width: 90% !important;
    margin-bottom: 1% !important;
}

.d-inline-block {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
</style>
```

This outputs the following:

[image]

As u can see the content is horizontal centered but not vertical? I'm trying to make something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: still can't get why ***row***s are not an option ? Anyway, making the `.control-section` as a **flex container** could be helpful.

Comment: Because I want container background to be an image

Comment: I have modified the code. Please check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bootstrap only solution :**

making the wrapper `div.control-section` as a *flex container* by giving it `d-flex` class and assign `m-auto` to the `.col-*` element.

> `d-flex`, `m-auto` are **Bootstrap** classes. Also, I added Bootsrap's `p-2` class to the wrapper `div.control-section` to have a little spacing if the viewport's height is less than the content height.

```css
.control-section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506765515384-028b60a970df") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
}
```

```html
<!-- importing Bootsrap (just for the demo) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Your code -->
<div class="control-section d-flex p-2">
  <div class="col-11 col-md-8 col-lg-4 m-auto" style="background-color: blue !important;">
    <section>
      <form id="account" method="post">
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
          <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
          <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
          <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
          <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="checkbox d-inline-block">
            <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                            <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                        </label>
          </div>
          <div class="d-inline-block">
            <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Password?</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <p>
            <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Password?</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a id="resend-confirmation" asp-page="./ResendEmailConfirmation">Resend email confirmation</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to center the "modal" abit more to the above to when displaying on mobile? Else user has to scroll down to get to login form

Comment: So, you want the modal to be at the top (not vertically centered) when on mobile ? If yes, then just add `mt-0 mt-md-auto` classes to `.col-*`. FYI, the content of your modal is long and that is causing the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**.html**

```
<div class="control-section centerArea">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 offset-5 centerAreaChild">Test</div>
</div>
```

**.css**

```
.centerArea {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 800px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.centerAreaChild {
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Check updated answer, i used your code and explained problem better

Comment: I have modified the code.. Please check..